# Etsy API Pagination with PHP

Tags: php, pagination, etsy

So, I'm fairly new to working with APIs, and am just trying to play around with using the Etsy API to display a certain set of listings.

By default, the API returns a set of 25 results, and can do a max of 100 at a time. I'd like to show more than that, so I'm trying to add pagination to my call. Here's what I've got so far:

```
<?php

//setting API key

define("API_KEY", XXX);

//setting request url

$url = "https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/listings/active?keywords=unicorn,unicorns&includes=Images:1:0&api_key=" . API_KEY;

while (isset($url) && $url != '') {

        $curl = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $response_body=curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);

        $response = json_decode($response_body);

        foreach ($response->results as $listing) {
                echo "<li>" . $listing->title . " ~*~ " . $listing->price . " " . $listing->currency_code . " ~*~ " . '<a href="' . $listing->url . '" target="_blank">View on Etsy!</a>' . "</li>" . "<br>";
        }

        $url = $response->pagination->next_page;
}

?>
```

I thought this would loop through and return the next set of 25 results, but it didn't. Anyone have experience working with this? Is there somewhere I'm getting tripped up?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `while` block, you are assigning the value of the `next_page` property to `$url`.
But the actual value is an `int`, 2, not an url.
Instead append the `next_page` to the initial url, as a query string variable.

```
$url .= "&page=" . $response->pagination->next_page;
```

See below an example on how you can isolate each process to a function.

We move the `curl` operation into its own function where it returns an object from `json_decode`.

We move the whole processing of the listings into a separate function, where for now, it just prints out the listings.

This second function is recursive, meaning, that if the next page exists it will call the first function, get the response, then process it.

```
<?php
//setting API key

define("API_KEY", 'br4j52uzdtlcpp6qxb6we3ge');

function get_listings($page=1){

    $url = "https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/listings/active?keywords=unicorn,unicorns&includes=Images:1:0&api_key=" . API_KEY;

    $url .= "&page=$page";

    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $response_body=curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    $responseObject = json_decode($response_body);
    return $responseObject;
}

function process_listings($responseObject){

    foreach ($responseObject->results as $listing) {
        echo "Title: " . $listing->title . PHP_EOL . 
            "Price " . $listing->price . PHP_EOL . 
            "Currency code " . $listing->currency_code . PHP_EOL . 
            'URL ' . $listing->url . PHP_EOL;
    }

    print PHP_EOL . "Pagination " . $responseObject->pagination->next_page . PHP_EOL;
    $next_page = $responseObject->pagination->next_page;
    if ($next_page) {
        $nextPageResponse = get_listings($next_page);
        process_listings($nextPageResponse);
    }
}

$firstPage = get_listings(); // page 1 is default
process_listings($firstPage);
```

Comment: Ah, perfect. Yes, I realized later that doing a var_dump of $url didn't return an actual url, which is why it wasn't redirecting, but was having some trouble finding a clean way to resolve that. Thanks for your help!